# Why async function appears as long-task?

Tags: javascript, performance, async-await, google-chrome-devtools

I am running the following code:

```js
function heavyCalculation(ms = 50) {
  const end = performance.now() + ms;
  while (performance.now() < end) {}
  console.log('main thread released ', ms)
}

async function blocker() {
  await heavyCalculation(10);
  await heavyCalculation(10);
  await heavyCalculation(10);
  await heavyCalculation(10);
  await heavyCalculation(10);
  await heavyCalculation(10);
  await heavyCalculation(10);
  await heavyCalculation(10);
  await heavyCalculation(10);
  await heavyCalculation(10);
  await heavyCalculation(10);
  await heavyCalculation(10);
}

setTimeout(() => {
  blocker();
}, 2500)
```

I would expect no long tasks to be marked in Chrome dev-tools. But this function appears as one:

[image]

Why? How to make this task not appear as a long task?

Comment: You are awaiting `heavyCalculation`, but that function doesn't return a promise.

Comment: you've called it `heavyCalculation` so I assume it really is a synchronous task that really does take a long time. Have you considered the possiblity of moving these tasks to Workers? Workers run on another thread and are sometimes the ideal solution to 'heavy tasks' that you don't want to block the rest of your ui